# Adding image icon to Winform datagridview margin

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wanted to know if and how I could go about adding a tiny image in the margin of a datagridview as shown circled in the image. i.e: each row should have the image in the margin.

Note: I do not want to add a new image column in the datagridview.

[image]

Comment: Kind a like the TreeView?

Comment: well, i am trying to create something like a hierarchical datagridview, except that the columns of the parent and the children are exactly the same (they are sourced from the same db table). My intention is that when the user clicks on the image icon in the margin of a certain row say A, it should hide rows B,C,D in the datagridview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, not complete but would be good for you to get started, this will add the same image to all the cells, click on the image will show some message (you can customize this):

```
    //CellPainting event handler to draw image on cell
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1 && e.Value != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.YourIMAGE, new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top + 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 4, e.CellBounds.Height - 4));
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() { LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor), new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left + e.CellBounds.Height, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Width - e.CellBounds.Height, e.CellBounds.Height), sf);                
        }
    }
    bool imageClicked;
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
       CheckIfClickOnImage(e);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckIfClickOnImage(e);
    }
    private void CheckIfClickOnImage(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e){
       Rectangle rect = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ContentBounds;
        rect.Offset(-rect.Width + rect.Height + 4, 2);
        rect.Location.Offset(0, 2);
        if (rect.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            imageClicked = true;
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You clicked on the image of the cell({0},{1})", e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex));
        }
    }
    //Clicking on a cell sometimes makes the clicked cell be in edit mode. So we can avoid this using some kind of flag
    private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (imageClicked)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            imageClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

### UPDATE

Your requirement is even much simpler than the code I posted previously, here is the code you need:

```
private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.yourIMAGE, new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left + 5, e.CellBounds.Top + 5, e.CellBounds.Width - 10, e.CellBounds.Height - 10));                    
        }
}
//To handle the click on a Row header, you can add custom code to a RowHeaderMouseClick event handler
private void dataGridView_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(e.RowIndex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This is good code to insert an image in the corner of every cell, however I need it only on the left margin of the datagridview and not in any cell. I cannot therefore use the cellbounds property.

Comment: @learn_code if so, it's even much easier, please see my update :)

Comment: Could you please explain to me how you perfectly calculated the values of 5 and 10 which you added and subtracted ? Is that by trial and error ? Could you possibly provide me with a link where I can read more about it? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @learn_code I just tried the values of 5 and 10, if you want, you can use other values, in fact, that value is called `Margin`, I used the same `Margin` for all the sides: `left, top, right, bottom`, 10 is the double of 5, the `e.CellBounds.Width - 10` is the actual width of the image with the `Left-Margin and Right-Margin` being the same 5, the same for `e.CellBounds.Height - 10` which is the actual height of the image with the `Top-Margin and Bottom-Margin` being the same 5.